# Изменить URL каталога Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

Есть каталог с товарами.Необходимо изменить с `/catalog/` на `/magazin/`

Попробовал сменить это дело в настройках конкретного инфоблока и правило обработки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результатов нет,что нужно еще сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Найдите в файловой системе папку `/catalog/` и переименуйте её в `/magazin/`.
2. Поменяйте в настройках компонента на странице `/magazin/`переменные отвечающие за URI